# Can I directly redirect to a specific net banking site through razorPay

Tags: razorpay

```
<button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="UserAction()">Search</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script> 

var options = {
    "key": "key", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    "currency": "INR",
    "name": "Acme Corp",
    "description": "Test Transaction",
    "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTalIw95OBcDFxFzLvh-F_6jAlHAm_yXZ-rJA&usqp=CAU",
    "order_id": "some_id",
    "handler": function (response){
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_signature)
    },
    "prefill": {
        "name": "name",
        "email": "email",
        'method': 'netbanking',
        "contact": jsonObject['notes']['mobile'],
    //     "card[number]": jsonObject['notes']['card_number'],
    //     "card[expiry]": jsonObject['notes']['expiry']
    },
    "notes": {
        "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": "#3399cc"
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
        alert(response.error.code);
        alert(response.error.description);
        alert(response.error.source);
        alert(response.error.step);
        alert(response.error.reason);
        alert(response.error.metadata.order_id);
        alert(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
});

document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

when am using this code it's just taking me to the net banking section, but I want to pick specifically a bank and go to the net banking portal of that bank.

[so basically I want something like this instead am getting some list of banks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHPHx.png)

but using the above code am getting like this
[see this is the response am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86vUH.png)

Comment: Does razorpay have docs or api examples that show this can be done?

Comment: I have not seen that one anywhere but, we have something similar to these customized bank options 
https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-links/api/new/advanced-options/customize/payment-methods/ 
here we have HDFC bank only 
i need something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js script. Once payment is created it will redirect to netbanking site directly.

Also, do not forget to specify bank code ([supported banks](https://razorpay.com/docs/build/browser/assets/images/TPV_BankList-Netbanking.xlsx)) during order creation.

```html
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <p>Redirecting to bank page</p>
  </body>
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>
  <script>
    var razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key: "{{ .ApiKey }}",
      image: "{{ .Image }}",
      callback_url: "{{ .RedirectURL }}",
      redirect: true,
    });

    var data = {
      amount: "{{ .AmountInPaise }}", // in paise, 1000 equals ₹10
      email: "{{ .Email }}",
      contact: "{{ .MobileNumber }}",
      order_id: "{{ .BankReferenceNumber }}",
      method: "{{ .Type }}",
      bank: "{{ .MappedBankCode }}",
    };
    razorpay.createPayment(data);
  </script>
</html>
```